# Is there any way to "prevent" users prevent the confirm box on Browser (firefox)

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser

I have some action with confirmation box (e.g: delete action), but when user click cancel and then they perform that action again and again, the browser will display a prevent option.

And after that, users can delete without confirmation.

Can I disable this dialog or is there alternative way to overcome this situation.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The dialog is there to prevent sites from abusing popups to deny users the ability to use the browser's interface; if you could disable it, so could abusive sites.

Instead of using a popup window, you might want to consider an HTML dialog box, that you position on top of the rest of your UI.